# Is there a limit on how many Single Entry Visas I can get for Thailand per year?

Tags: visas, thailand, repeat-visits

Is it possible to get multiple Single Entry Thai Tourist Visas per year?

I am currently considering going to Thailand 2-3 times in the next 12 months:

1. August/September for Kitesurfing in Ko Pha Ngan
2. December-February for Kitesurfing in Hua Hin
3. February-March for Kitesurfing in Hua Hin

2./3. are the most important to me, but if possible I would also like to go the 1. time.

I am simply planning to go as a Tourist, I don't intend to do any kind of work in Thailand. I would apply for the Multiple Entry Thai Tourist Visa, but am currently staying in Japan and don't intend to go back to my home country before. I understand I can only apply for the Multiple Entry Tourist Visa in places where I can claim residence.

I have entered Thailand the last time on 28th of December 2016 and stayed the maximum amount of possible days: 97 (60 day tourist Visa + 30 day extension + 7 day extension).

I am a German citizen/digital nomad being paid from the US.

Does anyone have any knowledge or experience with this?

Comment: How are you handling 2 & 3?  They seem to run together into a potential 120 day stay?

Comment: fly out for 1-2 weeks to Hong Kong or Singapore. and apply for another Visa from there.

Comment: How many previous entries/visas have you had before?  Singapore Thai consulate may not be the friendliest neighbor consulate. But you should be fine once or twice.

Comment: In my current passport there is only 1, from my stay this year staring late December. But it is a new Passport, in the one before I have quite a few as I was already staying in Hua Hin the year before on the 30 day Visa exemption 4 times in a row. Not going to Singapore is a good suggestion, I actually went to that consulate 2 years ago and they weren't very helpful. I'll probably then use one of the consulates mentioned by Jon. Any experience with the consulates in Vietnam?

Answer (score 2):

There is no etched in stone on the number of Single Entries visas you can apply for.  It is really up to consular officials to determine you are visiting or living under the radar.

As you have reasonable gaps between visits you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

@Tom is correct. There is no written policy affecting how many Single Entry Tourist Visas (SETV) you can obtain.

In practice, each neighboring Thai Embassy/official consulate may have soft limits on how many [consecutive] SETVs they may issue.   Having 20k THB equivalent as bank statement + proof of onward travel (POOT) may help when applying.

When arriving at the border, having 20k THB equivalent cash or traveler's check (and possible POOT) may help on the 3rd+ arrival.  Do **NOT** assume that ATM will be available.

Penang, Malaysia, Vietamine/Savannakhet Laos are friendly neighboring Thai official consultes for a quick, consecutive SETV.  Have fun and enjoy your trip.

---

Do double-check to see if you can obtain METV.  Might make life a little bit easier and flexible. SETV is good fallback though.

Comment: METV can only be obtained in a country you are citizen of or legal resident of.  Thailand has gotten strict about that, plus you need to show a lot more cash in the bank than you do for a SETV.

Comment: Thanks to both of your answers Tom and Jon! They are very helpful. I can provide them with proof of foreign income and have enough cash in my account for either Visa, so that shouldn't be a problem. I am just worried if I go almost back to back in February they will start asking questions. And the time from February onwards is when the wind is usually best for Kitesurfing. Having 20k+ cash on me is a good suggestion. I will go to the consulate in Osaka in the next few days and try and see if they can provide me with any 'soft' information about how they handle this.

Comment: You should be fine with SETVs the way you describe.  Get one SETV before you go each time. In February, you can hop to Penang to get another.  Don't rely on the 7 day extension, and it is a waste of 1900 baht IMO anyway.  Normally you only get 1 short term extension (30 days) per entry.  Exit and re-enter at land border to give yourself more options.  Double-check on METV availability as it may add flexibility to your trip. @Tom, OP already mentioned METV rules.

Comment: Thanks for all your input Jon, its much appreciated. So my current plan is to do as above with my 3. SETV applied for in Penang. Should I for some reason be denied this, it seems I still have a reasonable chance to get the VE on my return flight, if I have proof of foreign employment + income and 20k+ THB in cash on hand (and maybe even a booked return flight if I want to play it extra safe).

Comment: [FlyOnwards.com](https://flyonward.com/en/) might be a good option for bonafide POOT.  (Compared to less credible methods floating around on the internet)

Answer (score 0):

For many of us (depends on your passport country), arriving at an airport in Thailand you can get a 30-day non-renewable single-entry visa for free.  Arriving by land, it's 15 days instead.  For many trips, there is no need to get a visa in advance.  BTW when arriving, you will see a "Visa on Arrival" sign - ignore it, and go instead to the passport control desk, where they will stamp your passport with the visa stamp.

A little-known fact for New England folks: there is a Thai Consulate office located above Union Oyster House in Boston.  They can often issue a visa while you wait, including types you pay for that last longer.

Business visas are harder to get, because the meaning is different.  My company wanted me to have a business visa for speaking engagements, but I often could not get them.  "Business" means working a job in Thailand, or sales to Thailand.  A "tourist" visa is sufficient if you are representing a company at a conference or other presentation, so long as you are not negotiating sales.

Comment: This [mis]information should be a comment and it is also quite dated:  1) You can extend Visa Exempt (VE) entries for 30 days.  2) Land VE entries are now 30 days 3) Visa on Arrival (VoA) is a different program than VE scheme, 4) VE land entry is maximum 2 per calendar year per person, except for Malaysian nationals (air arrivals not affected). 5) Honorary Consulates no longer issue multiple entry visas of any category. 6) Working is not allowed on Tourist Visa (including volunteer work) and you are supposed to have a valid work permit.

Comment: It was all true as of January 2017, when I was last there.  Yes, VisaOnArrival is a different program, which is why I suggested walking past that sign and not stopping.  If Honorarary Consulates no longer issue ME visas, that is more recent than when I went in Aug 2016.  I did not say that working was allowed on a tourist visa; the presentations I gave WERE allowed.

Comment: The OP was about SETVs.  He could theoretically use VE for at least 1 of his entries which would give him 30 days and then extend for another 30 days (1900 baht + trip to immigration + any 'express service' fees local immigration boss may request).   A little pre planning with SETV gives OP more options, less stress, and should be cheaper.